# How to close terminal with my program?

Tags: command-line, c++

My code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <time.h>

#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
system("clamscan -r --log=clamavlog.txt --infected --bell /home/secon/Downloads");
sleep(1);
system("exit");
}
```

The problem is that my program do the scan, but the terminal remains open, i compile and run my program with termianl using: `gcc auto.cpp -o auto.exe` to compile, and `./auto.exe` to run.
I try to use `system("exit")` but it doesn't work.
P.S. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Seems like a design flaw. What exactly do you want your user to pay attention to? The action? The results? The fact that it ran at all? Present them with just that in an appropriate notification, indicator, or dialog.

Comment: I would like that hourly clamav scan Downloads folder, and when the scan's over i would like my program close terminal

Comment: It might be easier to implement that as a shell script.

Comment: When you use `system("...")` in C/C++, this will run the provided command in a separate subshell. Therefore running `exit` there will - as expected - only exit the subshell (which you won't notice) and not affect the parent shell or the terminal window..

Comment: Also, please don't name a Linux executable `auto.exe`. It has nothing to do with the Windows `.exe` file format and will just lead to confusion. Leave the file name extension away.

Comment: StackOverflow may have more help on programming, searched there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can not make your compiled application close the terminal window in which it is running, it is easy to make this happen by changing the way how you execute your program.

For example, if your executable application can be started using `./myprogramm`, you could just type the command below in your terminal to first run `myprogramm` and as soon as it finishes, run the `exit` command to close the shell and with it the whole terminal window:

```
./myprogramm ; exit
```

Or maybe it would be even better to only close the terminal window if your application exited successfully, without any error (indicated by an exit status code other than 0). You can use `&&` instead of `;` to run the second command only if the first command was successful:

```
./myprogramm && exit
```

A third alternative would be to replace the shell running in your terminal window with your application, instead of running your application inside the shell. That way, the terminal window will close as soon as your application exits and you don't have to exit the shell at that point any more:

```
exec ./myprogramm
```

One big difference between the first two approaches (`; exit` and `&& exit`) and the last one using `exec` is, that in the first case, you can kill the command you ran by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and you will be back in the shell, the window will stay open. If you used `exec`, this will also kill your application, but as there is no more shell inside which it is running, the terminal window will close immediately as well.